# iOS UITextField added via Code has no Cursor

Tags: ios, cursor, uitextview

i've a Viewcontroller and adding a UITextfield as a Subview. Everything functioning like expected, only that there is no Cursor in the textfield.

I use the following code to create and add the UITextField:

```
UITextField *funktionField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10+ line *38, myView.frame.size.width - 210, 31)];
funktionField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
funktionField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
funktionField.tag = line;
funktionField.delegate = self;
funktionField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
funktionField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
funktionField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[funktionField setEnabled:YES];
[myView addSubview:funktionField];
[funktionField becomeFirstResponder];
```

as said in the beginning. The keyboard appears and the text can be edited. The delgates are called but there is no cursor.

Am I missing something. When I add a textfield via UI Builder the cursor is there.

Regards Estartu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[funktionField selectAll:nil];
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. Looks like there was an AlertView that blocked the Cursor. Rearraged the Alerts some and the cursor is there.

Comment: Estartu, you should answer your own question then.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the same issue. I found that's because there's an input alert window when my app starts.
In alert delegate handler i don't call dismissWithClickedButtonIndex, so the focus cursor is held by the alert. and in any other input places of my app, cursor won't show.
I solved it by add [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO]; to each button handlers of the input alert window.